# `general-def` is not defined when used in `pre-` or `post-command-hook`

Tags: key-bindings

I have a function hooked to the `pre-` and `post-command-hook`, with the following code:

```
(when (window-minibuffer-p)
    (when (featurep 'general)
    (if (or (derived-mode-p 'prog-mode)
            (derived-mode-p 'text-mode))
        (unless (lookup-key
                    general-override-mode-map
                    (naked "RET")) (define-key general-override-mode-map (naked "RET") 'newline-and-indent)) ;; (general-def :keymaps 'override "RET" 'newline-and-indent))
        (when (lookup-key
                general-override-mode-map
                (naked "RET")) (define-key general-override-mode-map (naked "RET") nil) ;; (general-def :keymaps 'override "RET" nil)
                ))))
```

However, `general-def` does not seem to work, stating that it is undefined. `eval` does not seem to help, either, as when using `return` in the minibuffer, a newline is entered instead of selecting the option. `define-key` works fine, however.

Comment: If `general-def` is a macro, then you need to have loaded its defining file for it to be defined.

Comment: I thought that's what `featurep` was checking? It also doesn't work with `with-eval-after-load 'general`.

Comment: Try loading the source file (*.el) instead of the byte-compiled file (*.elc), if you need a **macro** defined in the file.

Comment: What if I don't know the location of the file? Would setting something like `load-suffixes` and then `require 'general` work?

Comment: Also, I tried adding `(load "general.el")` right after the `(featurep 'general)`, but it still didn't work.

Comment: Load it by hand, `M-x load-file general.el`, to check whether this is the problem. (You'll need to find where the file is.) You can use a `FILENAME` arg with `require`, but that won't load the file if the *library* has already been loaded (e.g. by `general.elc`).

Comment: You can also just evaluate the `defmacro` (assuming a macro is involved) by hand, and then see if that resolves the problem. So far, it's not clear what the problem is, is it?

Comment: So I tried `(load-file (locate-library "alloy.el"))` manually, which didn't work; how can I evaluate a `defmacro` in another file in my config, or manually?

Comment: Put your cursor after the defmacro sexp and hit `C-x C-e`.

Comment: Still not working; I'm at a complete loss. It's saying that `general-def` is an invalid function, by the way, despite it not being a function, in case that helps.

Comment: I've switched to the function version instead, `general-define-key`, which works, and have opened an issue on the GitHub repo; if a solution isn't found by then, I'll answer the question myself with a solution from the repo instead, with proper credits.